# Is VMware NSX a SDN solution?

Tags: vmware, cloud, vmware-nsx

VMware refers to the software defined data center. Their [brochure](http://www.vmware.com/products/nsx/) for NSX, their platform for network virtualization, does not include the term SDN (Software Defined Networking). However, their final result seems to be a separation of control plane and data plane, e.g., much of the forwarding decisions are made on the endpoints (processes in the hosts), not on the networking devices, which is a key element of software defined networking

However, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack) indicates that the 'OpenFlow protocol is a foundational element for building SDN solutions.' Is VMware's NSX a SDN offering or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. NSX is a software defined networking solution. VMware calls their solutions things like 'SDDC' (software defined datacenter) but the NSX solution is very much software defined networking. For an example of the common language used around this solution check here: http://www.networkworld.com/article/2172922/sdn/sdn-showdown--examining-the-differences-between-vmware-s-nsx-and-cisco-s-aci.html

Comment: That's what I thought too.  [This is my best definition of SDN](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19321/what-exactly-is-sdn) I can come up with.  A mysterious term indeed.

Answer (score 0):

YES,NSX is vmware SDN solution that support network virtualization in both east to west(inside your network and host ) and North to south (forward packets upstream some times out of your network) and you can use it in 2 type nsx-v(vmware products) and nsx-t(use it with other companies hypervisor)